# mozTCPSocket.listen API didnt work well?

Tags: firefox-os

Every time, when onconnect evet been fired, evt object awalys null, can't recieve anthing, what the problem is?

```
function startListen(){
var socketServer = navigator.mozTCPSocket.listen(1020);
socketServer.onconnect = function(evt){
    alert("connect");
    alert(evt);
    socketServer.close();
}
socketServer.onerror = function(evt){
    var error = evt.data;
    alert(error);
}
```

}

Comment: Is this a certified app?  I believe privileged apps have to use a port above 1024.

Comment: I useed port above 1024, it still get a null value,the function's first parameter.

Comment: where are you running the code?  In the Firefox OS simulator?

Comment: yes I want to establish tcp connection between two simulator, It is seems that the connection is been established, but the client can't receive the message.

Comment: It works for me in the simulator but not on my device currently: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1096616